# Create a HashMap in Scala from a list of objects without looping

Tags: list, scala, hashmap

I have a List of objects, each object with two fields of interest which I'll call "key" and "value".  From that I need to build a HashMap made up of entries where "key" maps to "value".

I know it can be done by looping through the list and calling `hmap.put(obj.key, obj.value)` for every item in the list.  But somehow it "smells" like this can be done in one simple line of code using `map` or `flatMap` or some other mix of Scala's List operations, with a functional construct in there.  Did I "smell" right, and how would it be done?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
list.map(i => i.key -> i.value).toMap
```

Comment: OP wants a `HashMap` not a `Map`

Comment: Warning: It does not support duplicated keys!

Comment: Does any map-type support duplicated keys? @RichardGomes

Answer (score 9):

Also:

```
Map(list map (i => i.key -> i.value): _*)
```

Comment: I suppose the advantage of this is that you can specify the type of Map you need, so it's more general pattern

Comment: @LuigiPlinge That is true. I much prefer using `.toMap`, as it is much more readable. If performance is of great concern, _maybe_ use `breakOut`.

Comment: I'm lost with that last part : _*  I get that the underscore is a placeholder for the functional variable, but I can't see how it fits in to that expression, nor the role of the asterisk and colon in that context.

Comment: OK, I got it now.  Map.apply with varargs.

Comment: Note: It does not support duplicated keys!

Answer (score 6):

To create from a collection (remember NOT to have a `new` keyword)

```
val result: HashMap[Int, Int] = HashMap(myCollection: _*)
```